# Why am I getting this error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

I get this error when deleting a `comment_title`:

```
NoMethodError in Comment titlesController#destroy

undefined method `comment_titles' for #<User:0x102e63bf8>
```

This is the destroy method:

```
def destroy
  @comment_title = current_user.comment_titles.find(params[:id])
  @comment_title.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :back}
  end
end
```

and the error refers to this line:

```
@comment_title = current_user.comment_titles.find(params[:id])
```

I don't understand what's going on here. Is it saying that current_user is nil? That doesn't make sense because I am logged in, and current_user works in other parts of my app. This also worked before, but after a lot of changes in my app, it doesn't work all of a sudden.

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

(Please don't ask me what I did from now until when deleting worked. I've done far too much stuff for it to be helpful.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you haven't got

```
has_many :comment_titles
```

in your `User` model

Comment: in your User model, fl00r said.

Comment: `in your User model, fl00r said.` – Kleber S. 2 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that User objects don't have a method "comment_titles". I can't be more specific without seeing your model code but I suggest that you look there for further clues. Is there a method or association called "comment_titles"?